# Code Splitting / Preloading Content while user is browsing?

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting

Using tools like Webpack we can enable code splitting and only 
load our application code asynchronously when required.

Example in the context of a react application with react-router.

```
Load initial page.

-> go to new route
---> webpack loads in the component file required asynchronous.
```

Webpack waits until the code is required in order to initiate the request.

My question is, once the base application code load, can we start loading the rest of the code, even before the user initiates the transition to the new route?

My view is that will prevent the user from waiting for the webpack chunk to download.

```
-> Load initial page
--> user sitting idle or browsing on home page
----> Start loading application code for rest of the application
---> user goes to new route (faster UX because code has already download in the background)
```

I hope this makes sense

Comment: How large are your chunks? And when you speak of _splitting_ your code, are you talking about about application (source) code and vendor (3rd party) code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ perhaps?

Comment: I realize this is a year late but you might find this useful: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/preload-webpack-plugin

Comment: Working with CreateReactApp, React 17.0.2: - magic comments for webpack: https://yuvrajpy.medium.com/frontend-performance-optimization-with-code-splitting-using-react-lazy-suspense-1e0d1a85e32c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes you can achieve this**. I will show one of the possible solutions.

Firstly let's create `backgroundLoader` for queuing required chunks:

```
const queue = [];
const delay = 1000;

let isWaiting = false;

function requestLoad() {
    if (isWaiting) {
      return;
    }
    if (!queue.length) {
      return;
    }
    const loader = queue.pop();
    isWaiting = true;
    loader(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        isWaiting = false;
        requestLoad();
      }, delay)
    });
}

export default (loader) => {
  queue.push(loader);
  requestLoad();
}
```

This function will load your chunks in background with 1 second delay (you can tweak it - for example start popping queue after for example 5 second or shuffle array of chunks).

Next you must register your `require.ensure` in queuing function `backgroundLoader`:

```
import render from './render'; // not relevant in this example
import backgroundLoader from './backgroundLoader';

let lightTheme = (cb) => {
  require.ensure([], () => {
    cb(require('./themeA.css'));
  }, 'light');
}

let darkTheme = (cb) => {
  require.ensure([], () => {
    cb(require('./themeB.css'));
  }, 'dark');
}

let pinkTheme = (cb) => {
  require.ensure([], () => {
    cb(require('./themeC.css'));
  }, 'pink');
}
backgroundLoader(lightTheme);
backgroundLoader(darkTheme);
backgroundLoader(pinkTheme);

export default (themeName) => { // router simulation
  switch(themeName) {
    case 'light':
      lightTheme(render);
      break;
    case 'dark':
      darkTheme(render);
      break;
    case 'pink':
      pinkTheme(render);
      break;
  }
};
```

Once you require your chunk in `switch` statement you pass `render` function containing resolve function. In `backgroundLoader` this function will be empty resulting only loading chunk to `head` of your app.

Full code for this example you can see on [WebpackBin](http://www.webpackbin.com/N1IzNXA5-) (you can check network to see how chunks are loaded in background)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you everettss, perfect/exact example of what I was looking for!